# customer analysis - book / blog recommendation?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, references

I'm new to the topic 'customer analysis' (in general) and need advice for a good starting point:
What is a good book / blog / tutorial on this topic?

My current situation is:
I have a lot of customer data which I cleaned and normalized. Now I want to figure out, what makes the difference of a bad and a good customer and how to make a bad customers a better customer.

Comment: Did you define what is a bad customer and what is a good customer in business terms? What's the difference between the two categories? You should probably first find what properties of each customer contribute to their good/bad status.

Comment: Yes, I'm working on this. But I think I shouldn't make this up by myself, instead there should be some books / other resources discussing these issues and challenges in customer-analysis. So I'm hoping someone can recommend a good book / resource on customer-analysis?